# How does a Setter Injection type is called

Tags: symfony

In the [Symfony 2 Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html) I saw that I can use 3 types of dependency injections :

- constructor
- setter
- property

It is quite clear when the Constructor Injection type is called (as soon as the object is created).

But how does the Setter Injection type is called ? Automatically ? Each time the service is requested ?

Thanks for your help,

Hakim

Answer (score 1):

Setter method runs only once and right after constructor. If you are looking for confirmation check `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder`::[createService](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php#L919) method. Because the services are not created twice and cached in the container setter function calls only ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then do you have any idea why in the doc, they state "You cannot be sure the setter will be called and so you need to add checks that any required dependencies are injected." If it is called after the constructor, why I would not be sure it will be called ?

Comment: Because you can create a service by hands like a simple PHP class or use a factory for it. And it is not always caused that setter will be called.

Comment: From my understanding, whether the service is using a class or a factory to create an object, at the end the constructor of that object will be called. Do you have an example when a setter will not be called ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Constructor will be called but setter method not. In this case construct arguments is nessesary.